# Display calculated values on pyplot axis without changing the scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis

I'm trying to reproduce a growth chart in python. The underlying data uses age in days, but I want to display the age (x) axis in 2-month intervals. Can this be done purely with axis/labeling options or do I need to add a calculated column to the data instead?

This is for self-learning, so explanations are even more welcome than code.

This is what I have:

```
# Import the WHO weight-for-age data from Excel
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

WHO_WFA = pandas.read_excel("PercentilesData.xlsx", sheetname="WGT_WHO")

# ... slice the dataframe and plot it
# steps omitted for brevity

# Plot with data:
plt.plot(maleAge, maleP01, maleAge, maleP1, maleAge, maleP3, maleAge, maleP5, maleAge, maleP10, maleAge, maleP15, maleAge, maleP25, maleAge, maleP50, maleAge, maleP75, maleAge, maleP85, maleAge, maleP90, maleAge, maleP95, maleAge, maleP97, maleAge, maleP99, maleAge, maleP999)

# Set up the axes/labels
plt.title('Weight-for-Age:  male (WHO)')
plt.xlabel('Age  (days)')
plt.ylabel('Weight  (kg)')
plt.axis([0,1900,0,30])
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: WHO Weight-for-age, male]

Instead, the x-axis should have ticks in 2-month increments (2,4, 6, 8, 10,12 ... to 60). I still need the data plotted using days though! So the x-axis value of 60 should be displayed as 2, 120 (days) is displayed as 4 (months), etc.

Thank you for any help!

**UPDATE 1**:
Dividing the values by month duration does result in the same curves, as long as the x-axis range is adjusted:

```
# month duration
mo = 30.4375
# divide age in days by month duration
plt.plot(maleAge/mo, maleP01, maleAge/mo, maleP1, maleAge/mo, maleP3, maleAge/mo, maleP5, maleAge/mo, maleP10, maleAge/mo, maleP15, maleAge/mo, maleP25, maleAge/mo, maleP50, maleAge/mo, maleP75, maleAge/mo, maleP85, maleAge/mo, maleP90, maleAge/mo, maleP95, maleAge/mo, maleP97, maleAge/mo, maleP99, maleAge/mo, maleP999)
# Adjust the maximum x value to 60 ...
plt.axis([0,60,0,30])
```

This produces:

[image: WHO WfA chart in months]

The last step is how to display the axis using major ticks at every 12 months and minor ticks every 2 months.

*For the truly curious:
Month length in the WHO growth charts is standardized to 30.4375 days. The data goes from 0 to 1856 days (60.98 completed months). For every day (0, 1, ... 1856), there are 15 weight values, each corresponding to a different percentile curve, for a total of 27,840 values.*

The original data is publicly available at: [WHO data/weight-for-age for boys](http://www.who.int/childgrowth/standards/wfa_boys_p_exp.txt)

Comment: What is the input data to this? Because months can in general have between 28 and 31 days, it's not clear what the output should be.

Comment: For growth charts, a month is considered 30.4375 days. The data ranges from 0 to 1856 days (60.98 completed months). For the purposes of the question though, the value used in the calculation doesn't matter.

Comment: So what's wrong with plotting the age divided by 30.4375? `plt.plot(maleAge/30.4375, maleP01, maleAge/30.4375, maleP1, ...)`

Comment: any chance you can give a sample data in code, or share the original data? (in order to give a more precise answer for others as well)

Comment: Actually nobody cares about the actual data here, what is needed is a [mcve] of the issue. Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) or the data from my answer on how to do this, next time asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a month has 30.4375 days, you can divide the days by the number of 30.4375 and obtain the number of months.

```
plt.plot(maleAge/30.4375, maleP01, maleAge/30.4375, maleP1, ...)
```

To define a specific tick interval, you can use a `matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator` with an interval of 12 for the major ticks and an interval of 2 for the minor ticks.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np

#create some dataset
age = np.arange(0,1857) # in days
df = pd.DataFrame({"age" : age})
for i in range(10):
    df["maleP{}".format(i)] = (3.8-0.9*(1+2*i/10.))*np.sqrt(age)/4.2

# Plot with data:
plt.plot(df["age"]/30.4375, df[["maleP{}".format(i) for i in range(10)]])

# Set up the axes/labels
plt.title('Weight-for-Age:  male (WHO)')
plt.xlabel('Age  (months)')
plt.ylabel('Weight  (kg)')
plt.axis([0,1900/30.4375,0,30])
plt.grid(True)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(12))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(2))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That helped me learn a lot. I'll review the guides you linked and mark this as the answer.